# Spotify iOS SDK - Error Domain=com.spotify.ios-sdk Code=500 "internal server error"

Tags: ios, spotify

I've copied the code from the **Simple track playback** project, when I first open the app I open the Spotify login page in Safari and get the callback correctly with a session. When I check the property `isValid` its YES but the `expirationDate` is same as current time.

When I then request playlistsForUserInSession the first time it's fine, but if I try to fetch it again I get the following message:

> Error Domain=com.spotify.ios-sdk Code=500 "internal server error"
>   UserInfo=0x16eb00c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=internal server error}

What seems to be the error?

I can also add that when I have fetched the playlist (first time) I can easily request to play music, fetch nextPage in the playlist and so, it there something wrong with `playlistsForUserInSession` in particular?

Comment: My guess is that this is the related to a known issue in the Web API where certain user's playlists are temporarily unretrievable due to lots of activity. This is a temporary condition and retrying this request after a short while usually works.

Comment: I've tried it for a week now at least and always the same. If I've fetched it one time, I need to log the user in again with Safari Spotify login and then it only works one more time again :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the issue.

I missed to send the read playlist flag in scopes when I requested the token, and therefore couldn't fetch the playlist.

Really would have hoped that Spotify send something different from "500 Internal server error" so I wouldnt spend hours to find this bug :)

So for all of you others, check so your scopes are correct!